# Extjs 6.0.2: setStyle of null

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am a creating a floating panel B inside another panel A( render to A);
When I close panel A, panel B also closes. But panel B still remains in the `zIndexManager.zIndexStack`. Thus, calling that component for changing its z and thus giving `setStyle` null error. Any idea?

```
var A = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            floating: true,
            alignOnScroll: false,
            resizable: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 450,
            height: 400,
            renderTo: B.id,
            items: [another Panel],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                style: 'background:#f6f6f6',
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center',
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'header',
                        tooltip: 'Submit',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-check',
                        scope: this

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'header',
                        tooltip: 'Close',
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-remove',
                        scope: this,
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });

        A.showBy(this.lookupReference('abcd'), 'tl-tr?');
```

Following error I get after closing the parent panel and reopening

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at constructor.setStyle (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:37862)
>       at constructor.setZIndex (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:38103)
>       at constructor.setZIndex (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:59257)
>       at constructor.onCollectionSort (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:124552)
>       at constructor.notify (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:72945)
>       at constructor.sortItems (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:73214)
>       at constructor.onSortChange (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:73123)
>       at constructor.onEndUpdateSorters (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:73329)
>       at constructor.fire (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:20226)
>       at constructor.doFireEvent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20170112151748:21133)

Comment: My question is why you render component A to component B using renderTo. I think it would be better if you use B.add(A) as it wouldn't break the framework's handling of the components.

Comment: @AngryLeo did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @hbulens wasnt able to solve this so tried what daniel suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually call destroy() on the floated components, when panel A is closed, it fixes the issue.